# How to make java 8 Stream map continuously with null check

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this piece of code

```
Coverage mainCoverage = illus.getLifes().stream()
    .filter(Life::isIsmain)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new ServiceInvalidAgurmentGeneraliException(env.getProperty("MSG_002")))
    .getCoverages()  
    .stream() // <==may cause null here if list coverage is null
    .filter(Coverage::isMainplan)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new ServiceInvalidAgurmentGeneraliException(env.getProperty("MSG_002")));
```

which is totally work fine but I think It's a little bit messy and not cover all the `null pointer exception` possible (see the comment).

I try to refactor this code into

```
Coverage mainCoverage1 = illus.getLifes().stream()
    .filter(Life::isIsmain)
    .map(Life::getCoverages)
    .filter(Coverage::isMainplan) //<== cannot filter from list coverage to one main coverage
    ...
```

Seem after I map the life to coverage it is not a list of coverage anymore. 
So the question is how I can refactor the first section into null safe and maybe shorten it?

Comment: I'm assuming `Life::getCoverages` returns a `Collection`, not individual `Coverage` objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Life::getCoverages` returns a collection hence the filter `Coverage::isMainplan` will not work, instead you should `flatMap` the sequences returned after `.map(Life::getCoverages)` then apply the `filter` operation on the `Coverage`:

```
Coverage mainCoverage = 
          illus.getLifes()
               .stream()
               .filter(Life::isIsmain)               
               .map(Life::getCoverages)
               //.filter(Objects::nonNull) uncomment if there can be null lists
               .flatMap(Collection::stream) // <--- collapse the nested sequences
               //.filter(Objects::nonNull) // uncomment if there can be null Coverage
               .filter(Coverage::isMainplan)
               .findFirst().orElse(...);
```

I've added a few things to your code:

1. I've added [`.filter(Objects::nonNull)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) after [`.map(Life::getCoverages)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) which you can uncomment given the elements returned could potentially be null.
2. I've added [`.flatMap(Collection::stream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) which returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.
3. I've added another `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` which you can uncomment given the elements returned after [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) could potentially be null.
4. We're then at a stage in which we can apply `.filter(Coverage::isMainplan)` and finally, retrieve the first object meeting the criteria via `findFirst` and if none then provide a default value via `orElse`.

I'd suggest having a look at the following blogs to get familiar with the `flatMap` method:

- [Java 8 flatMap example](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-flatmap-example/)
- [Understanding flatMap](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-flatmap)
- [A Guide to Streams in Java 8: In-Depth Tutorial with Examples](https://stackify.com/streams-guide-java-8/)

Answer (score 3):

Add condition in `filter` if list is not null and `i.isIsmain` then only filter, you can use `public static boolean isNull(Object obj)` or `public static boolean nonNull(Object obj)`

```
Coverage mainCoverage = illus.getLifes().stream()
.filter(i->i.isIsmain && Objects.nonNull(i.getCoverages()))
.findFirst()
.orElseThrow(() -> new ServiceInvalidAgurmentGeneraliException(env.getProperty("MSG_002")))
.getCoverages()  
.stream() // <==may cause null here if list coverage is null
.filter(Coverage::isMainplan)
.findFirst()
.orElseThrow(() -> new ServiceInvalidAgurmentGeneraliException(env.getProperty("MSG_002")));
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first part of your code you can put in a `filter(e -> e != null)` to unsure if the `List` is null it wont throw an NPE:

```
Coverage mainCoverage = illus.getLifes().stream()
         .filter(Life::isIsmain)
         .findFirst()
         .orElseThrow(() -> new ServiceInvalidAgurmentGeneraliException(env.getProperty("MSG_002")))
         .getCoverages()  
         .filter(e -> e != null) //<=== Filter out all null values
         .stream()
         .filter(Coverage::isMainplan)
         .findFirst()
         .orElseThrow(() -> new ServiceInvalidAgurmentGeneraliException(env.getProperty("MSG_002"))
```

---

The problem with your second code snippet is that I'm assuming `Life::getCoverages` returns a `Collection`, not individual `Coverage` objects, so you cannot call  `Coverage::isMainplan` on it

Comment: you are still streaming over `Life#getCoverages` which may throws a `NPE`.

Comment: @HPH I filter out all the null values so even if `List::getCoverages` returns null, this won't stream over the null values

Comment: you are still getting it wrong man, you can not stream over a `null` collection, the collection in this case is `life.getCoverages()` where `life` is the first *non null* `Life` whose `isIsmain()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave and the answers given here for it, break some principles of clean functional style coding.

Firstly, you should not mix terminal actions and creating streams again in the same chain/pipeline of code. Like in your example 
stream().findFirst().orElseThrow(..).stream().otherActions. 
It's really not a good practice and error prone. Ideally a chain of Java Stream API calls should work with a single Stream. That way it's easier to follow and reason about your code.

Secondly, you mentioned the this bit may hit Null Pointer exc:

```
.getCoverages()  
.stream() // <==may cause null here if list coverage is null
```

if getCoverages() is supposed to return collection, it should never return null, always return empty collection instead.

Break your code into separate logical pieces and give it some meaningful names:

```
Coverage mainCoverage = illus.getLifes().stream()
    .filter(Life::isIsmain)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new ServiceInvalidAgurmentGeneraliException(env.getProperty("MSG_002")));

Coverage mainplan = mainCoverage.getCoverages().stream()
    .filter(Coverage::isMainplan)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new ServiceInvalidAgurmentGeneraliException(env.getProperty("MSG_002")));
```

It looks much better than your starting point. I hope this helps.

Comment: although your answer does not directly answer my question but +1 for well explain and show me the real problem of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encapsulate the resulting `Collection<Coverage>` into an `Optional<Collection<Coverage>>` so that you can map over in a *null safe* manner.

```
final Supplier<ServiceInvalidAgurmentGeneraliException> customExceptionThrower = () -> new ServiceInvalidAgurmentGeneraliException(env.getProperty("MSG_002"));

final Collection<Coverage> firstMainLifeCoverages = illus.getLifes().stream()
    .filter(Life::isIsmain)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(customExceptionThrower)
    .getCoverages();

Optional.ofNullable(firstMainLifeCoverages)
    .map(Collection::stream)
    .orElseThrow(customExceptionThrower)
    .filter(Coverage::isMainplan)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(customExceptionThrower);
```